# What is the quota cost for call the LiveChatMessages in YouTube Streaming API?

Tags: youtube-api

Web are trying to create an app to retrieve live chat messages from a Youtube streaming live chat in real time.
We want to know the quota cost for using the LiveChatMessages. It is not mentioned in the YouTube Data API (v3) - Quota Calculator.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost